# ¿Cómo importar archivo de una carpeta precedente luego de usar setwd() en R?

Tags: r

Si fijo mi directorio en la siguiente carpeta.

```
setwd("C:/CARP-A/CARP-B/CARP-C/CARP-D/")
```

Entonces, si deseo cargar un archivo que está en la carpeta `CARP-D` solo tengo que escribir el nombre del archivo y listo.

```
# Por ejemplo.
read.csv("miarchivo.csv")
```

Pero si una vez que fijé mi directorio y deseo cargar un archivo que está en la carpeta `CARP-C`, por ejemplo, el archivo "miarchivo2.csv". ¿La única forma es la siguiente?

```
read.csv("C:/CARP-A/CARP-B/CARP-C/miarchivo2.csv")
```

O ¿existe una forma más abreviada que permita llamar al archivo `"miarchivo2.csv"`? Es decir, un argumento o una función que llame a archivos que están en una carpeta precedente.

Comment: Hola has intentado lo siguiente: read.csv("../miarchivo2.csv")?

Comment: R utiliza la misma lógica de directorios usada en terminal por sistemas Unix y GNU-linux: `"./archivo"` abre el archivo en el directorio actual. El camino relativo para moverse en niveles superiores en directorios es `"../archivo_directorio2"` `"../../archivo_directorio3"` así como @Poenix111 sugirió

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: Para hacer lo que quieres solo debes anteponer `..` a la ruta.

Answer (score 0):

Dependiendo de la estructura de tus directorios y/o datos, puedes ubicar el prompt de R en la raíz principal del directorio por ejemplo `setwd(C:/CARP_A/)`, luego listar todos los archivos con determinados formato, por ejemplo `*.csv` de la forma:

```
list.files(".", pattern = "*.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

El argumento recursivo permite navegar todas las carpetas que se encuentran por debajo de `CARP_A/`. y el argumento `full.names` te permite obtener toda la ruta donde esta el archivo, por tanto puedes leerlo sin problemas desde el directorio actual donde se encuentra el prompt de R.

Por otra parte, dependiendo la estructura de tus directorios, podrías ir cambiando el argumento `"."` donde puede indicar únicamente los paths donde quieres realizar la búsqueda.